# How to avoid having to re-disable serial ports in bios on restart?

Tags: windows, bios

I am using a windows computer as controller for some complicated custom hardware. Every time I upgrade the software, I have to follow 2 pages of instructions to disable bios com ports and then set them up again with my custom hardware. Where would I start with automating this? Is there a tool that can do this for me?

Disabling Bios Com Ports

```
•   If logged into windows, shutdown the computer.
•   Restart the computer and wait for text to appear.
•   Immediately press the F2 key a few times for the BIOS menu to appear. 
•   Use the ARROW and Enter keys to navigate and select options and the ESC key to move back. Use the Y or N key if indicated.
•   Select CONFIGURATION, use the DOWN arrow to select ONBOARD DEVICES, press ENTER.
•   DISABLE serial port 1_____
•   DISABLE serial port 2_____
•   DISABLE the Parallel Port _____
•   Use ESC key to exit. Select the EXIT menu; select Exit Saving Changes then ENTER, then Y.
•   The computer should after short delay. 



 From the desktop 
•   USB cables are connected to the flowmeter_____  MGA module_____ MCA module _____
•   Right click on the COMPUTER icon, then click PROPERTIES. 
•   Click Device Manager, double click PORTS to expand the submenu. 
•   With x representing a single digit number, two Kit Prog USB-UART’s (COM x), and one Prolific USB to Serial Comm PORT (COM x) ports are displayed_____.
•   Double click Prolific USB to Serial Comm PORT (COM x). 
•   Select the Port Setting tab (second tab).
•   select bits per second at 38400, 8, none, 1, none_____ 
•   Click ADVANCED,  Click Com port number, select COM3, and click OK_____
•   Remove the USB cable from back panel of the MCA _____
•   Double click Kit Prog USB-UART (COM x), assigned to the MGA_____ 
•   Click on Port Settings.
•   Select bits per second at 38400, 8, none, 1, none. 
•   Click the ADVANCED button. Click Com port number, select COM5, click (twice) OK_____
•   Remove USB cable from back panel of the MGA_____
•   Plug the USB cable in the back panel of the MCA_____
•    Double click Kit Prog USB-UART (COM x), assigned to the MCA_____
•   Select bits per second at 38400, 8, none, 1, none. 
•   Click the ADVANCED button. Click Com port number, select COM6,  click (twice) OK_____
•   Plug the USB cable into the back panel of the MGA module.
•   Make sure that COM3, COM5 and COM6 are listed on Device Manager, Ports.
•   Close the open windows. 
•   Restart the computer and wait for the computer to reboot windows.
```